# Issue Extracting Data from CSV and Appending to Dict

Tags: python, arrays, csv, dictionary, append

I'm getting an odd result when trying to insert cells of data from a table (a CSV here but could be other tables) into a list of dictionaries.

```
import csv

keylist = ["ID", "RN", "PD"]
myID = 0
t = []
t.append(dict.fromkeys(keylist, []))

with open("dataset.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        for j in range (len(row)):
            #printing here works as expected
            print keylist[j], row[j]
            #when appending to the value list the result is not as expected
            t[myID][keylist[j]].append(row[j])
```

The unexpected result appears to append the whole row instead of just the item at row[j].

For example if the CSV were something like:

```
0, "foo", "bar"
0, "foo2", "bar2"
0, "foo3", "bar3"
```

The result for t[0]["ID"] would be this:

```
[0, "foo", "bar", 0, "foo2", "bar2", 0, "foo3", "bar3"]
```

Instead of the expected result of:

```
[0, 0, 0]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict.fromkeys` initializes with the same value for all keys, so they all get the same instance of the list.  It's not meant to initialize with mutable objects.

Instead, use `collections.defaultdict` to create a new list if a key doesn't yet exist:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

keylist = ['ID', 'RN', 'PD']
myID = 0
t = [defaultdict(list)]

with open('dataset.csv',newline='') as csv_file:            # Use newline='' per csv docs.
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file,skipinitialspace=True) # handles spaces after commas.
    for row in csv_reader:
        for col,value in enumerate(row):
            t[myID][keylist[col]].append(value)

print(t[myID])import csv
from collections import defaultdict
keylist = ['ID', 'RN', 'PD']
myID = 0
t = [defaultdict(list)]

with open('dataset.csv',newline='') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file,skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in csv_reader:
        for i,v in enumerate(row):
            t[myID][keylist[i]].append(v)

print(t[myID])
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'ID': ['0', '0', '0'], 'RN': ['foo', 'foo2', 'foo3'], 'PD': ['bar', 'bar2', 'bar3']})
```

Note this still doesn't give you integers for your zeros.  You'll need more code for that.  Something like:

```
    for col,value in enumerate(row):
            t[myID][keylist[col]].append(int(value) if col==0 else value)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'ID': [0, 0, 0], 'RN': ['foo', 'foo2', 'foo3'], 'PD': ['bar', 'bar2', 'bar3']})
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem stems from this initialization of the dictionary:

```
dict.fromkeys(keylist, [])
```

The same list object is shared among all the dictionary's keys, and all items get appended to the same list.
The following initialization achieved the correct result:

```
t.append({k: [] for k in keylist})
```

Edit: a simple example to illustrate what's happening:

```
a = b = []
a.append(3)
b.append('foo')
a
```

gives:

```
[3, 'foo']
```

Because while a and b are different variables, they are referring to the same object. Likewise in your example, the different keys in the dictionary all refer to the same list object passed in the `fromkeys` method.